# How to add an option to make EMUI 10 wallpapers on HUAWEI themes studio

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I have p30 lite phone with EMUI 10 and i want to create my own wallpaper, but your themes studio doesn't support EMUI 10 it support EMUI 10.1 to 12, and for that I want you to add the option to create themes support the EMUI 10.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 10.1 theme package can be used for both 10 and 10.1.

Please select EMUI 10 for p30 lite theme development.